# How to push the forked repository which has submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

There is a `A` project and the A project has a submodule `S`
A
|-S
|-B
|-C

> A repo: git@github.com:**benjamin**/*A*.git
>   S repo: git@github.com:**owner**/*S*.git

To contribute some bug fix, I forked the `A` repository and cloned it.

`$ git clone git@github.com:benjamin/A.git`

and then to download a `submodule S` I commanded

`$ git submodule init`
`$ git submodule update`

Okay, the code tree are made well, and I fixed the bug at a file in `A` and a file in `S`.
To commit and push the two files,

```
$ cd S
$ git add modified_file
$ git commit -a -m 'submodule commit'
$ git push
```

But the push is not work.

> ERROR: Permission to owner/S.git denied to benjamin.
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Should I also fork `S` repository either? How do you do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a submodule is a git repo in itself.
You need to

- fork both repo,
- clone them both,
- make a symlink between `A` and `S` locally (just for your code to compile, ie don't bother with the submodule status of `S` locally)
- commit in both local repo your changes and push them to your respective fork
- make two pull requests (one for `A`, one for `S`)

Only the maintainer of `A` and `S` will be able to:

- apply your pull request in `S` and commit
- apply your pull request in `A`
- commit in `A`, recording the new SHA1 of `S` (submodule) and the changes in `A`.

---

[Mark Longair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223092/mark-longair) mentions that you can:

- clone your fork of `A`
- `git submodule init`
- `git submodule update` (that will clone `S` to the right SHA1, but with '`S`' as a remote, not '`forked-S`')
- `cd S`
- `git remote set-url origin <SSH-url-of-fork-of-S>`
- `git checkout -b my-changes-to-S`: make a branch in order to record your local modification, and to avoid being in a [detached `HEAD` mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714).

Comment: There's no need for a symlink, surely?  He can just `cd S` and `git remote set-url origin <SSH-url-of-fork-of-S>` and `git checkout -b my-changes-to-S`

Comment: @MarkLongair I suppose after a `git submodule init/update`? I have included your suggestion in the answer.