# how do I check in something that is a submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules, octopress

I want to be able to add everything that I edit in my octopress directory to github in case all the files die.

But I get this error:

```
➜  octopress git:(master) ✗ git add source/*
fatal: Pathspec 'source/about' is in submodule 'octopress'
```

How can I just make this octopress directory part of my overall git repository?

Comment: This is not supposed to happen. Did you follow octopress github pages setup doc ? See : http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/

Comment: I am not using GitHub pages but I did set it up per the docs.

Answer (score 2):

If a path is in a submodule, it would be part of the path declared in `.gitmodules` (at the root of the parent repo).
See "[List submodules in a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31695872/6309)"

```
git config --file=.gitmodules --get-regexp ^^submodule.*\.path$ | cut -d " " -f 2
```

You should be able to add files and push from that `source/about` submodule.

If you cannot push, that means the upstream repo of that submodule is not owned by you.
You could also consider [un-submodule-ing the submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162228/6309).

---

> How do I change ownership?

If you are in a repo you cannot push to, go to GitHub to that GitHub repo page, and [click the fork button](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/).

Then go back to your local repo and type:

```
git remote set-url origin https://<username>@github.com/<username>/arepo.git
```

(replace `<username>` with your GitHub account name, and `arepo.git` by the name of the repo you just forked)

Then try a `git push -u origin master`.

If your repo includes submodules (has a `.gitmodule` file), [the same principle would apply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11259732/6309).

Comment: I don't want to push back to the octopress repository but have it all stored in my repo in case something happens and I need to restore. So o am guessing the sub module is still owned by the octopress repo. How do I change owner ship?